# Ubuntu 20.04 after update, can't start/hangs and can't start recovery mode

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, recovery-mode

Ubuntu 20.04 after update, can not start/hangs and can not start recovery mode.

Last night I ran update when the message popped up.

Unfortunately since the reboot the system behaves funny.

Either it hangs at manufacturer start or hangs after Ubuntu start and never shows login screen.

Sometimes I can login by guessing the login-screen-window is there and in 50 percent of cases I pass successfully to main screen.

Then it either runs for a few minutes (check updates status "up to date"), starts flicking any window I open or does not respond to mouse-clicks. Every time it is different.

I learned at this site that something went wrong with the updates & I could try login to recovery mode (or previous versions) by pressing/holding shift or escape.

I am not succeeding. Perhaps I am timing it incorrectly.
Would there be another trick?

When booting the pc I also get message "System boot order not found. Initializing defaults. Creating boot entry 'Boot00xx'...." (where xx is ID).

I have HP elitebook about 5 years old.

I also have a bootable disk (running "try ubuntu" is ok, no strange behaviour). I guess I could reinstall the whole system as a last option.

I will be grateful for any tips. Thank you. Martina